# Error after change namespaces

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am newbie in ASP.NET and I have an issue that I can't solve.
I know, I know... there is a lot of information to research about this problem, so I was following all the options and threads, and I can't fix the problem :(

Basically I changed the name of my project and the namespaces. I setted the namespaces in the web.config file, located into the view folder.
Now I have the following problem:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required 
to service this request. Please review the following specific error details 
and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Models' could 
not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 31:     public class _Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml : 
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<Models.Transaction> {
Line 32:         
Line 33: #line hidden

Source File: C:\Users\xamor\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\3bcd733a\f5c0c449\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.yfewlf9d.0.cs    Line: 31
```

I now that is an autogenerated file built every time that the project rans, my web.config file is:

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="WebAPI" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Please, if anybody can help me I really appreciatte any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Btw, The problems appears after use the Fix Namespace tool from the Microsoft Marketplace https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-599079.FixNamespace